# AngularJS added currency symbol makes Number Blank

Tags: angularjs

I have below expression in AngularJS which displays a number with 2 decimal places.

```
{{detail.exit | number : 2}}
```

But when i add currency symbol as below, the number becomes blank on UI for few of the records.

```
{{detail.exit | number : 2 | currency}}
```

Anybody faces this issue before ? I i remove the currency symbol the number is getting displayed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works perfect

`{{detail.exit | currency:"USD$":2}}`

please replace currency symbol to whatever you want.

[Refer for more Details](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency)

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by removing the number : 2 from the expression since currency seems to be formatting the number in 2 decimal places internally.

```
{{detail.exit | currency}}
```